# a feel/ a feeling - the difference?

Tags: meaning

> a feel of sadness in the air.
>
> a feeling of sadness in the air.

Do they mean the same? I have checked these two words with a dictionary but I still can't put my finger on the difference.
Don't confine your explanation to my original 2 example sentences only.

Comment: Take a look at this chart: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+feel+of%2Ca+feeling+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3 "A **feeling** of" is **far** more common than the alternative. While I believe that "a *feel* of" **may** be a valid but less common way of saying the same thing, it will probably be interpreted as a mistake (and that you meant to say "a feeling of").

Comment: You also hear 'a sense of sadness in the air' in this context. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+feel+of%2Ca+feeling+of%2Ca+sense+of

Comment: **Feel** can be a noun, but it has quite a different meaning from the noun **feeling**.  Generally, **a feeling** is an emotional response, whereas **a feel** is a physical act of sensing by touch.  I would say the version with feel is incorrect. Also I have never heard anyone say "a feel of sadness" which has zero hits in google ngram viewer.

Comment: Billy, surprising, isn't it? You've never heard it but it's right here https://www.wordreference.com/definition/feel a sensation of something felt;
vague mental impression or feeling:
a feel of sadness in the air

Comment: @user1425: Imho, that's a rubbishy source. The example ***a feel of sadness in the air*** is barely English [by comparison with the standard](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+feel+of+sadness%2Ca+feeling+of+sadness&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) ***a feeling of sadness***. A competent articulate "literary" native Anglophone might feasibly have some reason for using the "unusual" form, but we shouldn't be encouraging learners to think they can do that.